# heroku application error, possibly devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

while trying to open my app in heroku I get the following a screen saying:

```
￼
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

The logs with the error are as follow:

> 2014-10-14T13:43:20.222314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=dry-reaches-7872.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=5356a97b-0f65-4af0-947b-fe1c42418c1d fwd="74.118.24.162"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-10-14T13:43:20.334555+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=dry-reaches-7872.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=768945b5-b9b6-4a0b-ba4f-fa0e389d4a29 fwd="74.118.24.162"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-10-14T13:47:16.518787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=dry-reaches-7872.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=3931e254-4f51-4c90-954a-6bbbf4fe4298 fwd="74.118.24.162"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-10-14T13:47:16.734809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=dry-reaches-7872.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=69b7e4bb-3953-46af-b608-1625c7556152 fwd="74.118.24.162"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

I tried to use devise for authentication in my project but failed, I think the error is some of the code from devise

Comment: Can you run `heroku logs` from your Terminal to check what the error is? And have you already migrated your production database? `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I ran the migration, i get the following error :                NameError: uninitialized constant Devise                                   it tells me to go to /app/config/initializers/devise, line 3, It belongs to devise, Devise.setup do |config| everything seems to be correct there.

Comment: Is `gem 'devise'` in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the devise gem in the Gemfile.Add this line to your Gemfile and run **bundle install**

```
gem 'devise'
```